# How to merge the same element in a nested list with Python?

Tags: python

I have an input in a nested list like:

> input = [ [1,2],[1,3],[1,5],[2,3],[2,5],[3,1],[3,3],[4,6] ]

And I want to merge the same element together as output like:

> output = [ [1,2,3,5], [4,6] ]

So far, I'd tried with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) , [unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and set().intersection to generate the result, but not as expected.

Is there any easier way to accomplish this?
I'll be appreciated with any idea can help.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the logic behind the output?

Comment: It is the *merge if there are common elements* logic. A very similar question was posted yesterday about that.

Comment: Let's see the code where you used defaultdict, unique and set. It will make a useful starting point.

Comment: If you need help debugging your approach: please include your code in the question ([edit]). If you're just interested in a working way I think I found a suitable duplicate. :)

Comment: Thank you all! I think I should check the post first which I didnt found.